# How to use OpenCV 4 in native C++ of Flutter (in 2022) (support Flutter 2.0/3.0)?

Tags: android, c++, ios, opencv, flutter

I need to write some C++ code which uses [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/), and the Flutter code will call those C++ code.

There are [tutorials](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) about writing C++ with Flutter, but I cannot find any up-to-date and easy-to-deploy solution about working with OpenCV. How to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is my solution.

## Features

1. Works for both Android and iOS.
2. Use static linking instead of dynamic linking. (Thus code size is much smaller.)
3. Up-to-date at **2022.08.08** working with OpenCV 4.6.0 and tested on both Flutter 1.x and 2.x and 3.0. (Since those APIs change rapidly and many articles are a little bit old.)

## Getting Started

NOTE: If you already have an app, you can skip this section :) This section assumes that you have no code at all.

The sample code can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/fzyzcjy/flutter_cpp_with_opencv).

**step 0**: Ensure you have [Flutter environment](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install), and have followed the [official "writing C++ with Flutter" tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop).

*NOTE*: It is a *must* to follow the step of "On iOS, you need to tell Xcode to statically link the file: ...". Otherwise, at our last step iOS will complain the symbol cannot be found.

*NOTE*: Also, you need to change the "strip style" as mentioned [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop#ios-symbols-stripped) for iOS. Otherwise, you will see [problems](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/issues/41) in iOS *release* build while in debug build everything works.

**step 1**: Write whatever code you like using OpenCV. For instance, I change `ios/Classes/native_add.cpp` to the following silly code, which is almost identical as in the [official tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop#closed-source-third-party-library):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

extern "C" __attribute__((visibility("default"))) __attribute__((used))
int32_t native_add(int32_t x, int32_t y) {
    cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(x, y, CV_8UC3);
    return m.rows + m.cols;
}
```

## Android

**Step 0**: Download the [Android](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.4.0/opencv-4.4.0-android-sdk.zip/download) OpenCV sdk from the [official website](https://opencv.org/releases/). Say I put it in `/Users/tom/Others/OpenCVRelease/OpenCV-android-sdk` in my desktop.

**Step 1.1**: Change the `android/CMakeLists.txt` to the content of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fzyzcjy/621fb575e7ca57beed6a55576418efd8). *NOTE*: First change the `OPENCV_BASE_DIR` to your folder.

Of course, the `lib/native_with_opencv.dart` should change the `.so` file name to `"libnative_with_opencv.so"`.

**Remark**: If you need more OpenCV features (such as `imread`), have a try using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/fzyzcjy/798fdd449ede7479966f41df8b2c1b36).

**Step 1.2**: Change the `android/build.gradle` as following:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        // [[[CHANGE 1: Make minSdkVersion bigger]]]
        // see https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14419
        minSdkVersion 21

        // [[[CHANGE 2: Add these flags and filters]]]
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions -std=c++11"
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, the `minSdkVersion` in your actual project (`native_with_opencv/example/android/app/build.gradle`) should also change to 21.

**Done!** Compile and enjoy it (and go to the next section for iOS)! If you see `1 + 2 == 3`, then everything is fine.

Bonus: If you [build in release mode](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) and [look at the apk size](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer), you will see our `.so` file is less than 1MB. Thus static linking and file size reduction does work :)

## iOS

**Step 0**: In `ios/native_with_opencv.podspec`, add:

```
  s.static_framework = true
  s.dependency 'OpenCV', '~> 4.5'
```

**Step 1**: Run `pod install` under `native_with_opencv/example/ios`.

**Step 2**: *Compile and enjoy!*

**Remark 0**: It is a must to follow the step of "On iOS, you need to tell Xcode to statically link the file: ..." in [the tut](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop). Otherwise, at our last step iOS will complain the symbol cannot be found.

**Remark 0b:** May need to check (verify) the following settings in XCode (which seems to be automatically included when dragging some files into XCode but not sure). Otherwise, your final IPA file (can be generated by [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size#ios)) will contain your `.cpp` *source file* besides compiled code, thus the source code is leaked.

The setting: Go to "Build Phase" of the "Runner" Target. (1) Look at "Copy Bundle Resources", and verify that your `.cpp` file or folders are *not* there. (2) Look at "Compile Sources", and verify your `.cpp` files *are* there. (You may need to first *add* your file in "Compile Sources" before removing it in "Copy Bundle Resources".)

**Remark 1**: If you are using other `.hpp` headers and see strange errors, such as OpenCV should be built with C++, or include of a non-modular header inside framework module, then may try this:

Create `xxx.modulemap` file containing the following `framework module the_name_of_your_module {}`. Then [change](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#module_map) your podspec to use this modulemap   `s.module_map = 'xxx.modulemap'`. Then run `pod install` again to refresh. Then compile and run and it should be OK.

My guess about this problem is that, Cocoapod generates an "umbrella header" (say vision_utils-umbrella.h), and your header is automatically included there. Thus, when compiling that header, things get broken. Thus, my method above tries to remove this umbrella header.

**Remark 2**: When you add or remove some c++ files, you may have to run `pod install` again (just like in step 1). Otherwise, you may see errors like "cannot find the symbol" (because Xcode does not look at your newly added C++ file).

**Remark 3**: If you see problems like `Failed to lookup symbol (dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, your_function): symbol not found)`, have a look at [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/ffi/issues/41#issuecomment-757597034) link. I seem to solve it by applying what is suggested in that comment (but not sure since also have tried other ways). If still not solved please reply to me.

---

(Optional) Explanations of how do the Android configuration work: (1) Originally, I just link the `core`, but there are hundreds of linking errors. Then I search and fix for each group of them. For instance, `error: undefined reference to 'carotene_o4t::...'` means I [need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665655/what-is-carotene-o4t-and-why-does-it-cause-issues-with-compiling-a-program-using) link with `libtegra_hal`, thus I add several lines. (2) Strangely, the `tbb` should be put *after* `core`, otherwise, it still does not link. (3) The `abiFilters` is needed, since `tegra_hal` does not support `x86` (thus no `.a` file exists). (4) `minSdkVersion` needs to be raised up, otherwise `fegetenv` will not be found.

Comment: Great tutorial, thank you!
I have a problem, though: as long as I stick to your example, using `cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(x, y, CV_8UC3)`, everything works fine. However, if I want to use `imread()` instead, I get errors like `error: undefined reference to 'Imf_opencv:: ....`.
I already added `imgcodecs` and `imgproc` to `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken Maybe you can create a question and link it here? I am not sure about your full situation given this short comment.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken I have edited my answer with my latest CMakeLists.txt (see "If you need more OpenCV features...").

Comment: Thank you very much! Now, everything's working as expected.

Comment: @Schnodderbalken Happy to hear that :)

Comment: just a note, if using `imgproc`, you want to place that BEFORE `core` in the `MakeLists.txt` for android.  So the order would be `imgproc` then `core` then `tbb`.

Comment: @ykonda thanks. I have updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/fzyzcjy/621fb575e7ca57beed6a55576418efd8

Comment: @ch271828n Tanks. Also, do you have any reference for integrating OpenCV for flutter desktop applications?

Comment: @AlexisToby I have not tried that. It should be similar to how you integrate any windows/linux/macos libs to flutter

Comment: @ch271828n Yes, but it's really complex, or maybe because am a beginner in Flutter, I couldn't make it working.

Comment: @AlexisToby You may make it a separate stack overflow question. I personally do not have the experience yet.

Comment: @ch271828n Okay. Thanks.

Comment: libjasper.a is not shipped with the OpenCV 4.5.5. When I remove it from the CMakeLists I get undefined reference on the libopencv_imgcodecs.a.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this awesome answer.

I need help here.
I want to use stitching methods. but I cannot figure out how to do it.

May you please tell me how may I call them?

Comment: Bro I still can't make it work. I have a cpp file but when running on iOS, it's not able to find lookup. Any ideas?